# how to add data dynamically in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to add data dynamically? I am not able to make same as static.

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1537/

Please check this fiddle and open panel it show menu as well as submenu options.

Now I need to make same on button click. I have add button. I want add menu option (which is submenu of **Additem** in panel) can we do this.

I get the button click event, but that is not working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1538/

```
$('#add').click(function(){
// alert('e')   
 $('#tree li').append('<ul><li> <span>jjjj</span><ul>')
         var tree = $('#tree').goodtree({'setFocus': $('.focus')});

})
```

Comment: that is wrong please check pleass 2 time add button

Comment: it should be like this if user press one time add button .then it displat one jjj inside addbutton. if user click 2 time it display two times or so on... but there is nothing iside jjj

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your `<ul>` and `<li>` tag.
Also, you probably don't want to add the new element to every `<li>` in the tree.
Try the following instead (http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1541/):

```
$(function() {
    var tree = $('#tree').goodtree({
        'setFocus': $('.focus')
    });

    $('.slider-arrow').click(function() {
        var anchor = this;
        var removeClass = "show";
        var addClass = "hide";
        var diff = "+=300";
        var arrows = "&laquo;";
        if ($(anchor).hasClass("hide")) {
            diff = "-=300";
            removeClass = "hide";
            addClass = "show";
            arrows = "&raquo;";
        }
        $(".slider-arrow, .panel").animate({
            left: diff
        }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $(anchor).html(arrows).removeClass(removeClass).addClass(addClass);
        });
    });

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#tree').children().last().append('<ul><li><span>jjjj</span></li></ul>');
        $('.goodtree_toggle').off();
        $('#tree').goodtree({
            'setFocus': $('.focus')
        });
    })
});
```

There also seems to be a problem with the `goodtree` plugin you are using.
The items only expand every second time you click them.
Ideally the plugin would use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to make sure that the expanding still works even if you change the tree, without having to re-initialize. Since you re-initialize the tree after every insertion, there are multiple event handlers attached to the nodes. So when you have an odd number of nodes inserted, it will toggle the element an even times (since you initialized it in the very beginning when it was empty), giving you no result.
You can fix it by removing all event handlers on the toggle before you re-initialize:

```
$('.goodtree_toggle').off();
```

I would really look for a better plugin instead.

Comment: can you please use fiddle

Comment: I found some more issues. Will update shortly including a link to the jsfiddle

Comment: Your issues should be fixed in the recent edit.

Comment: @shellfish please look the issue .If you got goot plugin let me know

Comment: @shellfish I think i choose wrong plugin..Because I found lot of issue .Like use click "additem' not image in real world application.but in my case it not work .mean it should collapse and expand when user click "assitem"

Comment: @shellfish do you ever use plugin of  menu wit submenu ? having nested collapsible row

Comment: I'd suggest to write one yourself. Should even be possible with pure CSS.

Comment: .:(@ i dont have much knowledge ..can you help if you have time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51479/discussion-between-user3530755-and-theshellfishmeme)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('#add').click(function(){

    var data = $('#tree li').html();
 $('#tree li').html(data+'<ul><li> <span>jjjj</span><ul>')
         var tree = $('#tree').goodtree({'setFocus': $('.focus')});

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1539/)

Comment: your answe is correct but I got one error

Comment: can you tell what error ?

Comment: These are the following steps .Open the panel first. Then click add button.it show collapsible image.expand the image .and also expand the jjj.then press again add button it show different image

Comment: is there any other way to show collablise  view in pannel .some time it is also not clickable

Comment: @any other nested menu way to implement

Comment: That looks like a CSS issue. You can make use available collapsible list here  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-collapsible-item-indented/

Comment: @niv these all are jquerry mobile collable list.I need nested list without jQM

Comment: @@navin last can we give different id's to "jjj" submenu and show alert of id when user click "jjj"

Comment: You can have a counter that increments on add btn click and give that as Id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51478/discussion-between-user3530755-and-navin)